# How to read txt file with some different style

Tags: python, pandas, text

This is my file

```
7377.0 Angebot: [100, 28, 176, 6, 73, 133, 77, 137, 174, 104, 191, 97, 156, 148, 164, 56, 107, 91, 177, 84, 161, 197, 90, 105, 41, 126, 12, 76, 25, 129, 135, 149, 85, 145, 110, 48, 53, 89, 122, 5, 121, 45, 141, 49, 165, 128, 167, 109, 75, 147, 168, 142, 93, 13, 44, 22, 120, 65, 139, 171, 87, 70, 184, 132, 158, 152, 144, 47, 16, 94, 74, 138, 66, 72, 82, 60, 59, 169, 194, 185, 71, 46, 119, 7, 86, 79, 190, 188, 101, 31, 14, 157, 117, 113, 124, 103, 125, 51, 112, 182, 29, 166, 78, 134, 33, 11, 155, 32, 57, 30, 175, 187, 92, 178, 127, 189, 180, 199, 160, 27, 21, 58, 62, 192, 198, 173, 68, 23, 136, 193, 106, 159, 83, 116, 102, 9, 96, 181, 99, 17, 38, 114, 10, 111, 143, 1, 200, 26, 24, 39, 15, 18, 172, 130, 63, 69, 55, 3, 183, 195, 88, 67, 34, 2, 150, 35, 64, 163, 140, 4, 36, 196, 50, 131, 118, 8, 162, 81, 154, 20, 42, 170, 98, 52, 186, 146, 179, 54, 80, 95, 153, 43, 61, 40, 151, 123, 115, 108, 19, 37]
```

The structure of every line looks like this

```
Double<SPACE>Angebot:<Space>[...,...]
```

I want to read that complete file

But with that it didn't work

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('results.txt', delimiter = " ")
df.head()
```

Example file:

```
855.0 Angebot: [5,1,2,3,4]
8895.0 Angebot: [5,8,9,6,4]
225.0 Angebot: [5,14,2,5,4]
7485.0 Angebot: [5,18,94,51]
```

The problem is, I can't create such a dataframe with pandas so I created an example textfile and this would have to be saved by myself, if someone can tell me how I can create this better I would be happy about tips.

What I want is something like

```
Double  |   Array
855.0   |  [5,1,2,3,4]
8895.0  |  [5,8,9,6,4]
225.0   |  [5,14,2,5,4]
7485.0  |  [5,18,94,51]
```

How could I read the file so that I get with `pandas` the output?

My question now is, how can I read the complete text file and save it in a dataframe so that the desired output comes out?

What I also tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('results.txt', delimiter = " Angebot: ")
df.head()
```

What I got

```
<ipython-input-13-9994bd826634>:2: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df = pd.read_csv('results.txt', delimiter = " Angebot: ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass engine as `python` while using `df.read_csv`

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep='Angebot:', engine='python', names=['Double', 'Array'])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
   Double          Array
0   855.0    [5,1,2,3,4]
1  8895.0    [5,8,9,6,4]
2   225.0   [5,14,2,5,4]
3  7485.0   [5,18,94,51]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the separator `\s+` and use `ast.literal_eval` to transform object "array" to actual array(list):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
from ast import literal_eval

file_txt = io.StringIO(
"""855.0 Angebot: [5,1,2,3,4]
8895.0 Angebot: [5,8,9,6,4]
225.0 Angebot: [5,14,2,5,4]
7485.0 Angebot: [5,18,94,51]"""
)

dataf = pd.read_csv(file_txt, sep="\s+", usecols=[0,2], names=['Double','Array'], converters={2: lambda x: literal_eval(x)})

dataf
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work for you:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
my_list = list()
f = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in f.readlines():
    l = line.strip()
    my_list.append([float(line.split()[0]), np.array(l.split('Angebot: ')[1].rstrip())])
pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['float', 'array'])
```

Result:

```
    float         array
0   855.0   [5,1,2,3,4]
1  8895.0   [5,8,9,6,4]
2   225.0  [5,14,2,5,4]
3  7485.0  [5,18,94,51]
```

Input file:

```
  855.0 Angebot: [5,1,2,3,4]
  8895.0 Angebot: [5,8,9,6,4]
  225.0 Angebot: [5,14,2,5,4]
  7485.0 Angebot: [5,18,94,51]
```